# Writing a perl cgi applications which runs as root

Tags: perl, cgi

I am writing a perl cgi application. At some point of time this cgi application needs to run  as root to access and write into a specific file. I would like to know how exactly I should go about doing this and the security precautions that I should take while doing it.

Answer (score 7):

You pretty much shouldn't.

If you can't avoid it, create a small and simple piece of code that runs with setuid root that does exactly that task and nothing more, or use `sudo` or similar to run a script that does just that.

Giving that file the appropriate permissions so that your web user can write to it (not necessarily read from it if that's not necessary) would be a better option.

Comment: +1 for "you shouldn't". Of course, OP will already use taint checks and compare the input against very tight rules. Weeding out `rm -rf /` from any additions to shell scripts is a good start ;-) Fail as default and only do the write when specific conditions are met.

Comment: Do you suggest using system("echo pass | sudo -s mine.pl params") to invoke it or is there a safer approach?

Comment: No passwords! Configure sudo with no password for your web users & that specific script. Make sure you validate strongly any parameter to your script before passing them to it.

Answer (score 0):

You must avoid doing that if you can at all times by all means.

If your program needs to write to the privileged file instantly, then go with [**Mat's** reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11733075/622310).
However, you can write the content somewhere else and run a cron job (say) every five minutes to copy the data.