# How to run a sentence as root in Perl

Tags: linux, apache, perl, debian

I have made a perl program that add users to the system using apache2. It works when i run as a root but i am using it in a register from a html therefore the program is running by that user (i think) and it doesn't work. The error in /var/log/apache2/error.log is : `"AH1215: can't open_a /etc/passwd Permission denied at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/registro.cgi line 60"` that line is the following

```
Linux::usermod->add($user,$password)
```

One solution must be give the permission +s using chmod +s to the registro.cgi but it is not allowed to use that way.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to allow an insecure CGI script to be able to create system users?

Comment: [Run specific perl script as root under Apache](https://serverfault.com/q/418767/145545), [Run superuser command from perl-CGI script via Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13680699/608639), [Running scripts from Perl CGI programs with root permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24942050/608639), [Running a perl cgi as root with *proper* security](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22819004), [Running scripts from Perl CGI programs with root permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24942050), [Writing a perl cgi applications which runs as root](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11733045), etc.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question indicates a lack of appropriate concern for system security, but if you *really* want to give this kind of privilege to a web app then a reasonable approach would be to have separate `setuid` programs that run with elevated privileges to perform the few root-level actions.

These `setuid` programs would be limited in what they can do, and you can do extra input validation and verification to make sure that they're not hijacked to do bad things. The web script could then invoke this `setuid` program as required.

I want to emphasise my warning about allowing a CGI script to manipulate `/etc/passwd`. It is very dubious behaviour for a web app and you should think very carefully before going ahead with your design.